# Creating an emberjs project in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I followed these steps to create an ember project on Heroku: https://www.heroku.com/emberjs

```
$ git clone git@github.com:heroku/ember-js-getting-started.git
$ cd ember-js-getting-started
$ heroku create --buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/emberjs.tgz
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

My question is, after cloning the repository, what exactly does the line:
`heroku create --buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/emberjs.tgz`

**EDIT:** I guess that to create an ember app you need to setup a node environment which is the only option you have for js:

`$ heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/nodejs`

I can set up my repo on github, then either manually on heroku or using the terminal create the `--buildpack` and push it.

Again, why then: `heroku create --buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/emberjs.tgz`, that's my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find everything about heroku buildpacks
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: Not everything. I made a edit to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Then you can read more detail about usage ember.js buildpack. Under Usage section :) https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-emberjs